# Hidden list with searcher - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

The searcher bar is not working, where did i get an error?
I get this error in the terminal when I added expanded:

**RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.**

I would like the hints from lost when searching to appear.Is everything logically arranged? I am new in flutter and not everything is clear to me.

```
Widget _profilePage(BuildContext context) {
 (context, state) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Align(
    alignment: const Alignment(0, -1 / 1.6),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          _buildSearchBar(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}  

List<String> newAllBreed = List.from(allBreed);

 static List<String> allBreed =
["Affenpinscher",
"Afghan Hound",
"Aidi",
"Airedale Terrier",
"Akbash Dog",
"Akita"];


void search(String value) {
   setState(() {
  newAllBreed = allBreed
      .where((string) => 
 string.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
  });
}

Widget _buildSearchBar() {
return Column(children: [
  ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 350),
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      onFieldSubmitted: search,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Search',
        hintText: 'Search',
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        filled: true,
        isDense: true,
        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            controller.clear();
          },
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10,
              vertical: 10,
            ),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.clear,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        prefixIcon: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            search(controller.text);
          },
          /// widget isntead of normal button
          // cancellationWidget: Text("Cancel"),
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10,
              vertical: 10,
            ),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.search_outlined,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
        ),
        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        border: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(5),
          ),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      children: newAllBreed.map((data) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(data),
          onTap: ()=> print(data),);
      }).toList(),
    ),
  )
]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is cool and you don't need to nest the `Widgets` unnecessarily. Since you are designing a typical search with list you can use `Column` widget instead of `SingleChildScrollView`. Simplified approach will be as below.

```
Column(children: [ 
TextFormField( .. ), // => Your search text box
Expanded(child: ListView( .. )) // => Search result
])
```

[image: Full view]
[image: Filtered view]

**Full Snippet :**  *For your understanding*

```
Column(children: [
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      onFieldSubmitted: search,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Search',
        hintText: 'Search',
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        filled: true,
        isDense: true,
        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            controller.clear();
          },
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10,
              vertical: 10,
            ),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.clear,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        prefixIcon: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            search(controller.text);
          },

          /// widget isntead of normal button
          // cancellationWidget: Text("Cancel"),
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10,
              vertical: 10,
            ),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.search_outlined,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
        ),
        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        border: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(5),
          ),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      semanticChildCount: newAllBreed.length,
      children: newAllBreed.map((data) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(data),
          onTap: () => print(data),);
      }).toList(),
    ),
  )
]);
```